# Function is Not Working for Two Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function as such:

```
def percent(a, b): 
    dataframes_list = [a, b]
    for df in dataframes_list:
        df.rename(columns={'A': 'q1', 'B': 'q2', 'C': 'q3', 'D': 'q4', 'E': 'q5', 'F': 'q6'},  inplace = True)
        df = (df.filter(like = 'q').groupby([df['Name'], 
            df['Type'],df['Date']]).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count()))
        df = df.reset_index()
        df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name','Type','Date'], value_vars= ['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5','q6'])
        df.rename(columns = {'value':'percent'}, inplace = True)
        return df

percent_df = percent(a, b)
print(percent)
```

I want to apply the function to two dataframes 'a' and 'b'. The function should make the necessary changes to both dataframes.
The above print statement only prints out dataframe 'a' and not dataframe b. Also, the dataframe 'a' doesn't seem to have the changes the function should have made. What is happening?

Comment: Your function returns during the first iteration of the loop. So it only processes `a` and returns the modified version of it. Create a list of updated dataframes and return that.

Comment: The only change you make in-place to the dataframe is `df.rename()`. Everything else is done with the copy returned by `df.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you indentation is a mess, so it's hard to determine if that is the root cause of the issue.

That being said, it looks like your return is placed inside your for loop, so it will exit after it processes the first DF. Try this:

```
def percent(a, b):
    dataframes_list = [a, b]
    for df in dataframes_list:
        df.rename(columns={'A': 'q1', 'B': 'q2', 'C': 'q3', 'D': 'q4', 'E': 'q5', 'F': 'q6'}, inplace=True)
        df = (df.filter(like='q').groupby(
            [df['Name'], df['Type'], df['Date']]
        ).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum() / x.count()))
        df = df.reset_index()
        df = pd.melt(
            df,
            id_vars=['Name', 'Type', 'Date'],
            value_vars=['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6']
        )
        df.rename(columns={'value': 'percent'}, inplace=True)
    return df


percent_df = percent(a, b)
print(percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning at the end of the first iteration of the loop, so it never processes the second dataframe.

Collect all the modified dataframes into a list and return that.

```
def percent(*dfataframes_list): 
    results = []
    for df in dataframes_list:
        df.rename(columns={'A': 'q1', 'B': 'q2', 'C': 'q3', 'D': 'q4', 'E': 'q5', 'F': 'q6'},  inplace = True)
        df = (df.filter(like = 'q').groupby([df['Name'], 
                                             df['Type'],df['Date']]).agg(lambda x: x.eq(4).sum()/x.count()))
        df = df.reset_index()
        df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name','Type','Date'], value_vars= ['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5','q6'])
        df.rename(columns = {'value':'percent'}, inplace = True)
        results.append(df)
    return results

new_a, new_b = percent(a, b)
print(new_a, new_b)
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation - it really helps. Appreciate it!